# How to use "pick up"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I have a question regarding the term "pick up" and I want to emphasize more on "pick up skills after a long time".

Can I say something like:

> I didn't use HTML for a really long time. It gets a little rusty. But if this position requires me to use it which is totally fine because I learned that before, **it would be easy for to me to pick up**.

Answer (score -1):

I think "pick up" is too informal to use in a resume; "refresh my skills" would be better.

Think about trying:

> My skills have become a little rusty, but I'm confident I can refresh them quickly.

It's not clear if you are working on a resume or practicing for an interview.

Comment: I disagree.  "Pick up" is perfectly fine, although to be logically correct you should add "again" afterward, *I haven't used HTML in some time, but it should be easy for me to **pick up again***